# How to execute code after vaadin login with spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vaadin

The user is setting the language and then login from a vaadin login view. I need the save the language the user set in a database.

I tryed using the addLoginListener function of the vaadin LoginForm. The problem with this is that it is triggered before the authentication finished. So someone could change the language of someone who he know the username of.

I also tryed [Spring Authentication Events](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/events.html). The Problem with this is that i dont have access to the vaadin session wher I saved the language that should be written in the database.

Comment: But you could listen for the login event in a class with VaadinSessionScope

Comment: @SimonMartinelli i tryed that but still couldn't access the vaadin session.

Comment: To be clear you are trying to access it like this: getUI().ifPresent(ui -> ui.getSession().getAttribute());

Comment: i use VaadinSession.getCurrent()

Comment: Have you tried to create your own class with @VaadinSessionScope and store the language there? and have the listener in the same class?

Comment: I tried that with the Spring Authentication Events class. But as mentioned above i couldn't access the vaadin session ther.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example. I would like to try out something

Answer (score 0):

You can find the `VaadinSession` you want in the authentication success handler using the current request:

```java
public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
​
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Optional<VaadinSession> maybeSession = VaadinSession.getAllSessions(
                request.getSession()).stream().findFirst();
​
        maybeSession.ifPresent(session -> {
            session.accessSynchronously(/* do something with session */);
        });
​
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }
​
}
```

This only works if you already have an existing `VaadinSession`; if your login mechanism uses something else than a Vaadin UI (such as a SSO), then the session doesn't exist yet and things become a bit more complicated.